# .hover() triggers on parent with children id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to track the mouse movement of my users, right now I have applied the .hover() binding to all the elements under body `$("body *").hover()`

When the mouse enters an element that is nested the "mouseenter" is trigger as many times as parent elements it has. That is OK for me but my problem is that the id I can access in the function is always the one of the child element.

Here is an working example: https://jsfiddle.net/jgyncf3w/1/
If you mouse over "p-1" at the same time that the divs it will print in the console "p-1 - in" 3 times. This does not happen if you are already inside one of the parent elements when you enter the child.

Changing the selector to `$("body")` doesn't solve my problem as it produces undesired behaviour when transition between children of the same parent.

My question is, is there anyway to keep the current behaviour but been able to access the correct id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `stopPropagation()` method of the event to stop the event bubbling up the DOM to be caputred by each parent element:

```
$("body *").hover(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.target.id.length > 0) {
        console.log(e.target.id + " - in");
    }
}, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.target.id.length > 0) {
        console.log(e.target.id + " - out");
    }
});
```

Also note that you can get better performance by using two delegated handlers on the `body` and checking the element which raised the event through the `target` property, instead of applying two event handlers to every single element in the DOM. Try this:

```
$("body").on('mouseenter', '*', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.target.id.length)
        console.log(e.target.id + ' - in');
}).on('mouseleave', '*', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.target.id.length)
        console.log(e.target.id + ' - out');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/jgyncf3w/2/)

Comment: This indeed stops the parent's trigger but I want to keep it. I just want to be able to access the correct id, why if the parent is responsible of the trigger I am getting the child id?

Comment: I end up using this and then going through the parents to get the ids so I'll mark it as correct.